# execution time of searching algorithms in c language(accuracy)

Tags: c

Im trying to compare those 3 searching algorithms,at first im using the time.h library but nothing happens,the output is always 0.00000 sec.Now im trying to use some counters on the loops.But i have a problem here too,can anyone help me with the code?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
void binarySearch(int a[],int,int,int*);
int interpolationSearch(int [],int,int,int*);
int linearSearch(int a[],int,int,int*);
int main()
{
    int size=10;
    int a[size],i,search,pos,pos2;
    double extime1,extime2,extime3;
    int t=0,b=0,c=0;
    int *counter1,*counter2,*counter3;
    counter1=&t;
    counter2=&b;
    counter3=&c;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        a[i]=i;
    }
    printf("ENTER A NUMBER TO FIND\n");
    scanf("%d",&search);
    //BINARY SEARCH
    clock_t start1,end1;
    start1=clock();
    binarySearch(a,size,search,counter1);
    end1=clock();
    extime1=(double)(end1-start1)*100000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("EXECUTION TIME FOR THE BINARY SEARCH IS %f SECONDS:\n\n",extime1);
    //LINEAR SEARCH
    clock_t start2,end2;
    start2=clock();
    pos=linearSearch(a,size,search,counter2);
    if(pos==-1)
    {
        printf("%d IS NOT PRESENT IN ARRAY.\n",search);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d IS PRESENT AT LOCATION %d.\n",search,pos+1);
    }
    end2=clock();
    extime2=(double)(end2-start2)*100000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("EXECUTION TIME FOR THE LINEAR SEARCH IS %f SECONDS:\n\n",extime2);
    //INTERPOLATION SEARCH
    clock_t start3,end3;
    start3=clock();
    pos2=interpolationSearch(a,size,search,counter3);
    if(pos2==-1)
    {
        printf("ELEMENT %d NOT FOUND\n",search);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ELEMENT %d FOUND AT POSITION %d\n",search,pos2+1);
    }
    end3=clock();
    extime3=(double)(end3-start3)*100000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("EXECUTION TIME FOR THE INTERPOLATION SEARCH IS %f SECONDS:\n\n",extime3);
    //COUNTERS
    printf("%d\n",t);
    printf("%d\n",b);
    printf("%d\n",c);
    return 0;
}

void binarySearch(int a[],int size,int search,int *counter1)
{
    int first=0;
    int last=size-1;
    int middle=(first+last)/2;
    while(first<=last)
    {
        *counter1++;
        if(a[middle]<search)
        {
            first=middle+1;
        }
        else if(a[middle]==search)
        {
            printf("%d FOUND AT LOCATION %d.\n",search,middle+1);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            last=middle-1;
        }
        middle=(first+last)/2;
    }
    if(first>last)
    {
        printf("NOT FOUND.%d IS NOT PRESENTED INT THE LIST.\n",search);
    }
}

int linearSearch(int a[],int size,int search,int *counter2)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        *counter2++;
        if(a[i]==search)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int interpolationSearch(int a[],int n,int k,int *counter3)
{
    int low=0,up=n-1,pos;
    while(low<=up)
    {
        *counter3++;
        if((k<a[low])||(k>a[up]))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        pos=low + (int) ((double) (up - low))*(((double) (k - a[low])) / ((double) (a[up] - a[low])));
        if(a[pos]==k)
        {
            return pos;
        }
        else if(a[pos]>k)
        {
            up=pos-1;
        }
        else
        {
            low=pos+1;
        }
    }
    return (-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
#define MAX_ITER_COUNT 1000000
...
clock_t start1,end1;
start1=clock();
for(iteration = 0; iteration < MAX_ITER_COUNT; ++iteration) {
  binarySearch(a,size,search,counter1);
}
end1=clock();
extime1=(double)(end1-start1)*100000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/MAX_ITER_COUNT;
printf("EXECUTION TIME FOR THE BINARY SEARCH IS %f SECONDS:\n\n",extime1);
```

This repeats the search for a million times to make the time measurable. Although with this approach you would end up adding calling overhead also. To avoid that, you may want to put the loop inside the function to be profiled.

Check [this](http://codepad.org/zHBAG6vZ) link for a timer implementation and performance measurement using `gettimeofday` and `timersub`

Comment: Should i add another library?Its not running.

Comment: @nickL You can use a small value of `MAX_ITER_COUNT`, for example `10`, `100` or `1000`. Check [here](http://ideone.com/2I9RsW)

Answer (score 1):

`clock()` is the cpu time, if you want the execution time you need `clock_gettime()` on POSIX compliant operating systems and there are solutions for other operating systems too, read this [link](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/04/c_c_tip_how_measure_elapsed_real_time_benchmarking#clockgettme).

Answer (score -3):

According to the [cplusplus.com reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) I'd suggest defining a little benchmark method like below:

```
<template class Func>
public inline static double measureExecutionTime(const Func& method) {
    clock_t time = -clock(); //start
    method(); //execute method
    time += clock(); //end
    return time / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC; //return execution time, in seconds
}
```

---

Sorry for posting c++ code, I hope you can translate that piece to c-code. My university course decided not to teach the differences between `c` and `c++` anymore :/

Comment: This is about [tag:c] not [tag:c++]

Comment: increment `c`, and you have `c++`

Comment: c++ is a horrible language, specially the `template`s thing.

Comment: `c` at all is a shi**y language, as well as its various successors